# Compiling Objective-C in terminal on Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, makefile

I am quite new to both writing a makefiles and Objective-C language. I am trying to compile a small test application with this Makefile:

```
Q = @
INCLUDE_PREF = -I

CC := gcc 

#Here the source files are specified

list_src_files = $(shell find . -type f -name "*.m")
SRCS := $(subst ./,,$(call list_src_files))

#Here is our include files

list_include_dirs = $(shell find . -type d -name "include")
INCLUDE_LS := $(call list_include_dirs)
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(INCLUDE_PREF).
INCLUDE_DIRS += $(addprefix $(INCLUDE_PREF), $(subst ./,,$(INCLUDE_LS)))

#Flags used with gcc

CFLAGS = -Wall -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation -g -O0 $(INCLUDE_DIRS)

#Here all object files are specified

OBJS := $(SRCS:%.m=%.o)

#Here is the name of target specified

TARGET := Convertor

#Here is our target

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
           @echo "Building target"
           $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.m 
     @echo "Building objects"
     $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
      $(Q)-rm $(OBJS) $(TARGET) 2>/dev/null || true
```

The code I am trying to compile is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


#define DEBUG
#define VALID_PARMS_NBR   3   

#ifdef DEBUG
# define dbg(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,  ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
# define dbg(...)
#endif



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < VALID_PARMS_NBR) {
    NSLog(@"Usage of this program is: prog_name arg1 arg2");
  } else {
    dbg(@"Parameters: %s, %s, %s\n", argv[0], argv[1], argv[2]);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

The warning compiler is throwing me everytime:

```
clang: warning: -framework Foundation: 'linker' input unused
```

Could you, please, point me, where I did mistake in a Makefile? And why this warning appears?

I was looking through the similar questions, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning indicates the `Foundation` framework statement isn't used, and can be removed:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -fobjc-arc -g -O0 $(INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Removing it from the `CFLAGS` line should resolve things.

Warnings are just that — to warn you about behavior that might not necessarily be a problem, but something to be aware of. Despite this the program might compile anyway, although it's good that you have the mindset to fix it.